# Removing/keeping specific columns based off their contents in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset

df:There are in reality thousands of both variants and IDs

```
     variant1 variant2 variant3 variant4
ID1   0/0         0/0      0/0     0
ID2   0/0         0/0      0/0     0
ID3   0/0         0/0      1/1     0
ID4   0/0         0/0      0/0     1
ID5   0/1         0/0      0/0     0
```

Desired outcome:

```
     variant1 variant2 variant3 variant4


ID3   0/0         0/0      1/1     0
ID4   0/0         0/0      0/0     1
ID5   0/1         0/0      0/0     0
```

I would like to only keep rows if they have 0/1, 1/1 or 1 in them.

I have tried `dt[grepl(0/1", df),]` for each iteration but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a base R or data.table way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `if_any` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    filter(if_any(everything(), ~ . %in% c("0/1", "1/1", "1")))
```

-output

```
    variant1 variant2 variant3 variant4
ID3      0/0      0/0      1/1        0
ID4      0/0      0/0      0/0        1
ID5      0/1      0/0      0/0        0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
dt[ Reduce(`|`, lapply(dt, `%in%`, c("0/1", "1/1", "1"))),]
```

-output

```
    variant1 variant2 variant3 variant4
ID3      0/0      0/0      1/1        0
ID4      0/0      0/0      0/0        1
ID5      0/1      0/0      0/0        0
```

---

The same option can be used in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[dt[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, c("0/1", "1/1", "1")))]]
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(variant1 = c("0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/1"
), variant2 = c("0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0"), variant3 = c("0/0", 
"0/0", "1/1", "0/0", "0/0"), variant4 = c("0", "0", "0", "1", 
"0")), row.names = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, this worked really well. What does the "|" function in Reduce mean? Does ".SD" in the data.table mean apply to whole table?

Comment: @tacrolimus The `|` is OR operator.  It checks for elementwise OR in each of the vector from the list output of `lapply` and returns a single vector of TRUE/FALSE.  i.e. if there is a single TRUE in the same position, it returns TRUE or else FALSE. 2) `.SD` - subset of data.table.  If we don't specify anything in `.SDcols`, it will take the whole columns